# How to customize SSRS columns/rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to be able to change header text and spacing issues in our SSRS report viewer.  Ours is not the most recent reversion (no newer than 2010). But the only information I can find have nothing to do with code:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645971(v=SQL.100).aspx

I can't figure out if they expect us to edit it in the design view or what.  But does anyone know how or a source that gives coded examples of how to do this?[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you normally edit report layout using report builder?  Not report viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you need VS 2005 or 2008 to do this. You need to install BIDS and SSRS.

http://www.petri.co.il/sql-reporting-services-create-edit-reports.htm

As for where the reports are - try your source control or ask someone...

You are looking for the .rdl file(s) that correspond to your report.

Comment: actually mine were .rdlc files, but still wouldn't have found them otherwise